# use python glob to find a folder that is a 14 digit number

Tags: python, glob

I have a folder with subfolders that are all in the pattern YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  (timestamp).

I want to use glob to only select the folders that match that pattern.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) doesn't support regular expressions, you'll have to brute-force creating the match string.  One way is to take advantage of the fact that character ranges in `[]` are expanded:

```
C:\temp\py>mkdir 12345678901234

C:\temp\py>C:\Python26\python.exe
Python 2.6.2 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (release26-maint, Apr 14 2009, 21:19:36) [M
C v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./' + ('[0-9]' * 14))
['.\\12345678901234']
>>>
```

I took advantage of the fact that in Python, multiplying a string with an integer *n* results in that string being repeated *n* times.

Of course, you might want to go ahead and put in a check to verify that the given path is actually a directory:

```
>>> [path for path in glob.iglob('./' + ('[0-9]' * 14))]
['.\\11223344556677', '.\\12345678901234']
>>> [path for path in glob.iglob('./' + ('[0-9]' * 14)) if os.path.isdir(path)]
['.\\12345678901234']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  For now I was using this:

[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9]

Which basically has the rules for the format I described (limiting months, days, hours minutes to their respective ranges), I just wasn't sure if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: @mikec: It might be simpler to stick with `'[0-9]' * 14` and then only accept the timestamps which can be successfully parsed with `datetime.strptime`, if you *really* need to ensure that all the timestamps are valid.