# Use glob to find arbitrary length numbers

Tags: python, glob

I'm looking for the glob-pattern that find all files containing the pattern `myfile_[SomeNumber].txt`

My naive attempt was

```
glob.glob("myfile_[0-9]*.txt")
```

but this also find all files on the form `myfile_[SomeNumber][AnyStuff].txt`

This answer shows how to do it for a fixed length, but that not what I want in this case.
[use python glob to find a folder that is a 14 digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692706/use-python-glob-to-find-a-folder-that-is-a-14-digit-number)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably confusing regular expression syntax with glob constructs.  `[0-9]*` in globbing  means "a single digit followed by zero or more of *any* character".  So drop the `*`.

In *extended globbing* there is a qualifier of "one or more", but that is not supported by `glob`, so there is little choice but to use a regular expression, i.e. do your own filename pattern matching.  There are several ways to do this, here is one:

```
import os
import re

files = []
for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    if re.match(r"myfile_[0-9]+.txt", fname):
        files.append(fname)

print files
```

Note that the RE is not exactly the same as yours, I use `+` which means "one of more of the preceding pattern", an `*` would mean "zero or more" - so the digits would be optional, which could be what you want (I'm not sure).

The bulk of the code could be done as a list comprehension, but that would arguably loose some readability:

```
files = [fname for fname in os.listdir('.') 
        if re.match(r"myfile_[0-9]+.txt", fname)]
```

Comment: This would also match a file named "myfile_123.txt.exe", since re.match accepts matches at the beginning of the string. It's better to use re.fullmatch instead.